# jquery mobile javascript function is not defined until reload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website i'm working on using jquery mobile **jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js**  I have a couple javascript functions defined in my page. The page is written in **aspx**.  once the page is loaded I have radio buttons that call the functions however I get a "function is not defined" error.  However if I refresh the page, then it all works fine.

I have also viewed the source of the page, and saved the source as a plain html page, and it works fine.  Does anyone know what kind of issue php might be causing thats making it that my functions are undefined until a refresh?

Comment: how do you include that JS function? is it a plain inline JavaScript? are you waiting for the DOM to become ready before you bind your functionality? a little code sample would definitely help here

Comment: just i created some custom functions in that pages.... I am trying to call that function on button click etc

Comment: that is still very broad answer - could you include a sample code (don't need to be your own, just an example of the structure you use there) for us to see?